# HTML/CSS responsive table

Tags: html, css

I have built a simple order form with delivery, billing and bank-account holder's address.
Right now the thing is formatted as a big HTML table:

```
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
|         | DelAddr | BillAddr | BankAddr |
| Name    |         |          |          |
| Street  |         |          |          |
| City    |         |          |          |
| Country |         |          |          |
| Tel     |         |          |          |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Naturally this is not responsive and looks incorrect on mobiles, as the Wordpress template I use is a responsive one.

How do I (without JS if possible), make the table responsive, so that when the viewport gets smaller it looks like

```
+---------+---------+
|         | DelAddr |
| Name    |         |
| Street  |         |
| City    |         |
| Country |         |
| Tel     |         |
+---------+---------+
|         | BillAddr|
| Name    |         |
| Street  |         |
| City    |         |
| Country |         |
| Tel     |         |
+---------+---------+
|         | BnkAddr |
| Name    |         |
| Street  |         |
| City    |         |
| Country |         |
| Tel     |         |
+---------+---------+
```

Is that even possible using CSS alone? The difficulty is displaying the description column on every "splitted" row.

Comment: Why don't you just use divs instead of a table? That makes it easy to realize a responsive layout.

Comment: @SvenBieder The problem with this specific instance is that in the desktop view, the meta-data about each address are listed on the left only once, whereas in the desired mobile view, the meta-data is replicated in each row to correspond to the address entry.

Comment: @Phire because you consider your users as illiterate and they don't know how an address is build?

Comment: @SvenBieder Because the developer requested it in a certain format and there are no obvious reasons in the question to dismiss their stated requirements.

Comment: @Phire Ok, no problem, there are a lot of strange design specs going on out there. You have two good answers how to use a responsive table below.

Comment: I asked pretty much the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637016/how-can-i-represent-tabular-data-responsively I got a nice simple answer too.

Comment: The problem is that I need the address split in even worse parts (the real form has 7 lines for the postal address), because it is directly fed to other applications and I don't want to rely on regex-parsing house numbers and postal codes out of arbitrary-forced addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Chris Coyer has a very nice article on this: [**Responsive Data Tables**](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

Here's a quote:

> The biggest change is that we are going to force the table to not behave like a table by setting every table-related element to be block-level. Then by keeping the zebra striping we originally added, it's kind of like each table row becomes a table in itself, but only as wide as the screen. No more horizontal scrolling! Then for each "cell", we'll use CSS generated content (:before) to apply the label, so we know what each bit of data means.

Comment: That is hideously messy. Its far better just do two tables and hide one using media queries.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers - I couldn't disagree more. You should *never* duplicate your content.

Comment: Well, only one version will be displayed, so technically you aren't. True a search engine might object, but given that we are talking about tabular data, which could well repeat anyway, I don't think thats an issue. Besides which, who wants a billing form indexed anyway? The only time I would say don't do it is if you were having to type the tables out yourself, but I doubt thats the case here. The server language can generate two tables just as easily as it generates one.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers The users who pay by the KB for their data will totally thank you for making them download identical sets of data.

Comment: Genius solution, but it has to be hand-crafted for each of the forms and it also requires that the desktop view is in row mode, which is absolutely unreadable

Comment: Have you considered using a fieldset/legend combo?  They could be made to appear inline on wider displays, and display vertically on narrower ones.  I'm not opposed to using tables with forms, but the way you have the data grouped is unnatural for tabular data.

Comment: Fieldset would display duplicate data in the desktop mode, also it is not guaranteed that the input elements in one row are in one horizontal line.

Comment: Look, hiding images does not make sense. But we are not talking about images here, we are talking about a couple of hundred extra bytes.

Comment: Besides which, I just looked at the entire article you linked to, and in the example used there the row headings are duplicated many more times than had you just done two separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use bootstrap it's completely free and great for responsive design... .And I think you don't need js for that. Still it's included it's a greatcss libary